# Split only first part after /

Tags: javascript, split

I am using split function like this :

```
function getFirstPart(str) {
    return str.split('/')[0];
}
function getSecondPart(str) {
    return str.split('/')[1];
}
```

For first part it is working as expected, but for second part i want everything behind first /.
For example in `/stub/787878/hello`, I want stub as first part and `/787878/hello` as second part.

How to make pattern for such condition.

Comment: What does it return now ?

Comment: it returns 787878 only and not the /hello part behind it.

Comment: `stub` and `787878hello` is what you are expecting?

Comment: @Matías I need /787878/hello from getSecondPart(). whole part after /stub.

Comment: including slashes?

Comment: Just `shift` of the number of parts you don't need, and `join` the rest

Comment: @Matías yes. exactly.

Comment: @adeneo can you please tell me how to make split pattern ? like str.split('/(.+)')[1] ? P.S. : it doesn't work, i tried various patterns.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5323pxwf/

Comment: @adeneo code snippet is not giving any result on console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use `split`, find the slash, and take the string to the left and right of it:

```
function divideAtSlash(str) {
  const index = str.indexOf('/', 1);
  return [str.slice(0, index), str.slice(index)];
}
```

The second argument (`1`) to `indexOf` tells it to start matching at the second character, because in this case we want to skip over the leading slash.

The first element of the returned tuple will be `/stub`, not `stub`. If you want the latter, then

```
return [str.slice(1, index), str.slice(index)];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```js
const str = '/stub/787878/hello/911';
const [, firstPart, ...rest] = str.split('/');
const secondPart = '/' + rest.join('/')

console.log('first part: ', firstPart);
console.log('second part: ', secondPart);
```

Comment: I got this : SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: Where are you running the code? You need ES6 support

Comment: Try copy/paste the code into the chrome's console or running it with the "Run code snippet" button. Is the result what you are expecting?

Comment: if i put /stub/787878/hello/911 will i be getting /787878/hello/911 ? then yes this is what i want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130335/discussion-between-matias-and-sharad-chauhan).

Answer (score -1):

i guess `getSecondPart()` is returning 787878 in your example.
you need to check how many parts you have in your arrayy after splitting the string and then return every part except the first.

```
function getSecondPart(str) {
    var astr = str.split('/');
    str = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < astr.length; i++) {
        str += "/" + astr[i];
    }
    return(str);
}
```

CODE IS NOT TESTED, I just want to give you an idea.

Comment: Your `for` loop is just a verbose way of writing `join`.